# How to subscribe to a parent Directive's EventEmitter emit?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-event-emitter

I have a 3rd party `SortDirective` which I am extending:

```
export declare class SortDirective implements CanDisable, HasInitialized, OnInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {
    readonly sortChange: EventEmitter<Sort[]>;
    ....
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[customSort]'
})
export class AbxCustomSortDirective extends SortDirective implements OnInit {
    ....
}
```

I can't figure out how to subscribe to the `SortDirective` `sortChange` emit? The point is I don't know where in the `SortDirective` `sortChange` is emitted. And I don't think I should. The only thing I know is once it is emitted I want to subscribe to it (and emit some custom event for my component subscription).

UPDATE: here's the reproduction on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wdmk8l?file=main.ts).

Comment: Have you tried `this.sortChange.subscribe()` within your custom directive?

Comment: @e-maggini Yes - it does not get fired... But I have noticed a weird thing: the same base directive (`SortDirective`) is originally applied to the table component itself and to the sortable table cell headers (which represent the directives too)... So maybe it has to do with that and I need to apply `AbxCustomSortDirective` to header cells, too. Unfortunately, cannot share the code - this 3rd party components are private...

Comment: I took a closer look: it is not a problem of the cell. Probably it has something to do with inheriting a directive itself. I've debugged the code and after emitting `SortChange` in the base class the subscription in the inherited class just does not react.

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://blog.nrwl.io/macgyvering-directives-3e41e7b93e1e

Comment: @e-maggini Thank you very much! Actually instead of extending the directive, I've just added the 'modifier' directive. And resolved my issues. Please, post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: What is the "modifier" directive? Maybe you should post YOUR answer to the degree possible? Just upvoting my comments is fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of fighting with the inherited directive logic (where an inheritance is actually not needed), I just used the approach suggested [here](https://blog.nrwl.io/macgyvering-directives-3e41e7b93e1e) and resolved my issue.

So now it looks like this:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[extSortingPaging]'
})
export class AbxExtSortingPagingDirective {
  constructor(
    @Host() @Self() private tableComponent: TableComponent<any>,
    @Host() @Self() private sortDirective: SortDirective
  ) {
    this.sortDirective.sortChange.subscribe(() => {
      console.log('Sort changed!!!');
    });
  }
  ...
}
```

Called in the component:

```
<bc-table
  sort
  extSortPage
  [extPaginator]="additionalFieldPaginator"
  [extDataSource]="measureLocationAdditionalFields.controls"
>
```